# How to check for the details of components in interface builder in XCode?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

i am quite new to XCode. I was looking through some of the sample codes from Apple Developer sites. I understood code for the same but I am not having a clear idea on how to check for the type of components used in the application and how they are linked with the .m and .h file.

Can anyone help me with how interface builder connects to .h and .m files and how I can check that for the project that I have not created?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did not like the source codes given in apple developer site because it seemed pretty complex to me when I started learning.. 
try this site out http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=143
It will give you a basic idea of how to get started with adding components and everything else. 
I would also like to suggest that you dont use interface builder for adding components but rather add them using code... it would give you more flexibility... ( but thats just my suggestion)...

Comment: thanks learner2010 for the reply. The site looks good. I will try. Anyways i got it resolved after labor of 3 hours.

Comment: yeah no problem.. remember to accept answers here if you feel that they are correct...